# Kubernetes Microsoft SqlServer unstable

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, sql-server-linux

I followed an official documentation on how to [deploy Microsoft SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-sql-server-containers-kubernetes?view=sql-server-ver15) in Kubernetes as a container on Azure Kubernetes Service. There is a couple things I'm noticing and it's concerning:

### Two containers in Kubernetes

When I execute `kubectl get pods` shows 2 instances of mssql with one `Running` and one `Pending`. Even if I remove all the pods with `kubectl delete pods -l app=mssql`, Kubernetes would recreate both pods.

[image]

### Occasionally it goes down

As I use my application at some point I start getting errors:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

And

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)  --->
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: Connection reset by peer.

I haven't done anything different from the official documentation besides adding the container limits. I believe the container doesn't even hit those limits. I had Kubernetes running on 2x 4GB VMs and as I was adding SqlServer I added 3rd 4GB VM So that Kubernetes has enough CPU and Memory to work with.

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 300m
    memory: 2.5Gi
  limits:
    cpu: 400m
    memory: 3Gi
```

### Login Failed in logs

The last but not least if I run `kubectl logs mssql-xyz` sometimes I see the following in the logs:

> 2020-10-28 13:24:16.83 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason:
> Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT:
> 10.240.0.4] 2020-10-28 13:24:18.09 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.

Obviously the password is correct in my application. It may be related to other errors, I don't know...

---

Any thoughts on all this? How can I make it work stable without any errors?